# When try to uninstall vlc, the option attempt to uninstall complete desktop environment

Tags: linux, debian, vlc-media-player, kde

I'm trying to uninstall vlc and vlc-nox using the following command

`apt-get remove --purge vlc libdvdcss2 vlc-nox`

But the message that I got is several packages will be uninstalled, too, including kde desktop, as shown below:

The following package will be DELETED

> amarok* apper* ark* bluedevil* browser-plugin-vlc* dolphin* gwenview*
> k3b* kcharselect* kde-baseapps* kde-baseapps-bin* kde-plasma-desktop*
> kde-runtime* kde-style-oxygen*   kde-window-manager* kde-workspace*
> kde-workspace-bin* kde-workspace-randr* kdebase-runtime* kdepasswd*
> kdepim-runtime* kdeplasma-addons* kdesudo* kdm* kfind* khelpcenter4*
> kinfocenter*   kio-audiocd* klipper* kmenuedit* kmix* konqueror*
> konqueror-nsplugins* konsole* kscreen* ksnapshot* ksshaskpass*
> ksysguard* kwalletmanager* kwrite* libakonadi-calendar4*
> libakonadi-contact4* libk3b6* libkcddb4* libkcompactdisc4*
> libkonq-common* libkonq5abi1* libmarblewidget19* libokularcore5*
> libsmokekdecore4-3* libsmokekdeui4-3* libsmokekfile3*
> libsmokekhtml3* libsmokekio3* libsmokeknewstuff2-3*
> libsmokeknewstuff3-3* libsmokekparts3* libsmokektexteditor3*
> libsmokekutils3* libsmokeplasma3* marble-plugins* okular*
> okular-extra-backends* phonon* phonon-backend-vlc*
> plasma-dataengines-workspace* plasma-desktop* plasma-nm*
> plasma-runners-addons* plasma-scriptengine-python*
> plasma-scriptengine-ruby*   plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba*
> plasma-scriptengines* plasma-wallpapers-addons*
> plasma-widget-folderview* plasma-widget-lancelot*
> plasma-widgets-addons* plasma-widgets-workspace*   polkit-kde-1*
> python-kde4* python3-pykde4* qapt-batch* ruby-kde4* ruby-plasma*
> software-properties-kde* systemsettings* vlc* vlc-nox*
> vlc-plugin-pulse*

How can I uninstall vlc and vlc-nox without uninstalling my desktop environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands `apt-cache depends [packagename]` and `apt-cache rdepends [packagename]` can be helpful in discovering what packages are causing a cascading uninstall like this, but I usually use `aptitude` and the [Debian  packages site](https://packages.debian.org/) when tracing dependencies.  On Debian Jessie, this cascade is triggered by removing `vlc-nox`:

1. `vlc-nox`
2. `phonon-backend-vlc` (satisfies `phonon-backend`)
3. `phonon`
4. `amarok` / `kde-runtime` / `plasma-widgets-addons` / (etc)
5. `kdeplasma-addons` / `kde-plasma-desktop` / `plasma-desktop`

There are other options for the `phonon-backend` requirement, so installing either `phonon-backend-null` or `phonon-backend-gstreamer` first should prevent the removal cascade:

```
$ sudo apt-get install phonon-backend-gstreamer
```

After that, your `apt-get remove` command should work as expected.

---

Alternately, it is possible to force removal of specific packages with `dpkg`.  The `--force-depends` flag turns dependency problems into warnings. **This is not recommended and can leave your system broken.**

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends [packagename]
```